# survival::survreg user-defined Beta distribution

Tags: r, survival, beta-distribution

I have a data set with a dependent right-censored variable distributed over the Beta distribution. Please do not offer *flexsurv* package. It is necessary to describe the function of my Beta distribution for use in the AFT regression survival model **survreg**. An example from [the book M. Zhu](https://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/Rsurv.pdf), I substituted the functions known to me, but I can not describe the ratio of the first and second derivatives of the density function of the Beta distribution :

```
# Beta Distribution - User-defined code for 'survreg'
a = 1.2; b = 0.2

myb <- list (name = "beta",

init = function (x, weights, ...)
{
mean <- sum (x * weights) / sum (weights)
var <- sum (weights * (x - mean) ^ 2) / sum (weights)
c (mean, var)
},

density = function (x, parms)
{
  cbind (
  pb (x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b, ncp = 0), # F - Cumulative Distribution Function
  1 - pb (x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b, ncp = 0), # S = 1 - F - Survival Function
  db (x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b, ncp = 0), # f - Density Function
  ?, # f'/ f - the first derivative of the Density function
  ? # f''/ f - the second derivative of the Density function
)
},

quantile = function (p, parms)
qb(x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b, ncp = 0),

deviance = function (...)
stop("deviance residuals not defined")
)
```

I believe that this is due to the derivatives of the `beta` function, the `gamma` function, `digamma` & `trigamma` function in the base package **r**, but my Math level does not allow them to be applied.

Comment: I believe that to obtain the [first derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of++x%5E(a-1)(1-x)%5E(b-1)%2Fbeta(a,b)) and the [second derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+x%5E(a-1)(1-x)%5E(b-1)%2Fbeta(a,b)) of the probability density function Beta distributions that contain the glorious Euler *Beta* function, you should refer to the shareware website **WolframAlpha**.